# a defined dictionary gets undefined when i dict trough it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an funtion that makes a get request to an server and the server respond to it and i need to check the status code but when i use the key of the responded dict i get the log that its undefined, but when i do this in the console i do get the status code.

```
function check_object(time_link_check){
        var x = $.get(time_link_check);
        //1
        console.log(x)
        //2
        console.log(x.status)
    }
```

1. 

```js
Object {
  readyState: 1,
  getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(e),
  getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(),
  setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(e, t),
  overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(e),
  statusCode: statusCode(e),
  abort: abort(e),
  state: state(),
  always: always(),
  catch:
    catch (e),
  …
}
```

2. `undefined`

Comment: `$.get()` returns [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) not the result, as detailed in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: There is no `status` property in the jqXHR object contained in `x`. Why are you expecting there to be one?